# Файл не сохраняется когда он .jar

Tags: java, xml, файлы

Хотел поработать с файлами, программка работает в IntellijIdea, но когда создаю .jar файл он не сохраняет изменение на файл, выдает ошибку. Вот код:

```
public void saveMarshall(Group currentGroup) {
    try {
        File file = new File(new URL(getClass().getResource("/resources/office_list.xml").toString()).getPath());
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Group.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(currentGroup, file);
    } catch (JAXBException exception) {
        Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, "saveMarshall threw JAXBException", exception);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Расположение .xml файла:
[image: расположение xml файла]

Выдает FileNotFoundException или вот это:

```
янв 27, 2017 1:10:26 AM com.google.javafx.objects.Application saveMarshall
SEVERE: saveMarshall threw JAXBException
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException:        file:\D:\IdeaProject\JavaFXInstaBot\out\artifacts\JavaFX\JavaFXWorkXMLFile.jar!\resources\office_list.xml (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:108)
at com.google.javafx.objects.Application.saveMarshall(Application.java:94)
```

Comment: изменение файла хранящегося в jar не поощряется. Это разумеется можно сделать, но через костыли, советую все таки сохранять в файл лежащий рядом с jar  или в какой то другой директории, но никак не внутри архива.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а как сделать так чтобы никто не видел этот файл(как правильно спрятать его)?

Comment: никак, рядом обычную директорию создаешь и туда пишешь файлы.

Answer (score -1):

При создания джарника Windows немного по-другому воспринимает расположение файлов в вашем случае посоветую вам попробовать сделать `File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/office_list.xml");`. Сам сталкивался с такой проблемой)))    Возможна ещё одна причина: внутри ваш xml файл  ссылается на пустой файл

Comment: При чем тут Windows?